# c# postasync returns unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code. It is returning a `401 Unauthorized` although it works perfectly on PostMan.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

var data1 = new { fName = "Sam", lName = "F" };
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(data1.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

var response = result.ToString();
```

What could be wrong here in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Start adding headers as they appear in Postman, one-by-one to your request.
One or more of them is what you're missing.

You can also use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to verify that how you **think** your request looks like, is how it **actually** looks like.

Comment: @Captan it actually returns forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1);
var contentData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(url,contentData);
```

if it is not working, then you have problem with roles. Your API must be have a role authorization too, not just a token.

Comment: I updated the question, the error is `403 forbidden`